# What is faster, creating winform controls using designer or programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have to create some complex winforms using Visual Studio (VB.NET) and I have the choice, either, doing it using the designer or programmatically. Is there any difference in terms of runtime performance ?

Thank you.

Comment: When you do it with the designer, it builds a `.designer.vb` file, which sets all of the properties, just as if you would have done everything programatically yourself.

Comment: In addition to what Joe Enos said: If you add a constructor (sub new()) to your Form, a call to `InitializeComponent` will be added in there - that's the method that sets up the control you added in the designer.

Comment: In terms of development performance, creating controls using designer is much faster, than creating them programmatically. Also you can consider runtime performance to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there is a significant difference. Maybe in some exceptional cases the designer assigns some properties that do not need to be assigned which might reduce performance a little bit, but not significantly.
On the other hand, the designer adds a lot more stability when managing control lifetime. From my perspective and experience, creating controls manually or dynamically always introduces programming overhead that otherwise is done by the designer. I'd suggest to use the designer as long as there is no strong requirement to do it manually.